# PHP how to display element from select menu

Tags: php, html

How can I display other elements from a table when I choose an element from a select menu? I have tried to do something, as you can see in the link below, but I don't see anything :(

http://faous.net/test/profile/page1.php

```
<html>
<header>
    <title>test PHP</title>
</header>
<body>

    <h1>Formulaire</h1>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="get">
    <?php
        echo "<select name='sub1'>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

            echo "<option value='" . $row['nom'] . "'>" . $row['nom'] . "</option>";
        }

        echo "</select>";
        echo "<br />";
        $result2=mysql_query($sql);
        $base=mysql_fetch_array($result2);
        //$nnnn= $_GET["nom"];
        //$aaaa=$_GET["base"];
        //$bbbb=$_GET["hauteur"];
        //$cccc=$_GET["rayon"];
        $nnnn = $_GET[$row];
        $aaaa = $_GET["base"];
        $bbbb = $_GET["hauteur"];
        $cccc = $_GET["rayon"];

        echo "Nom: $nnnn <br /> Base: $aaaa <br />  Hauteur: $bbbb<br />  Rayon: $cccc";
        echo "<br /> ";

    ?>
    </form> 

</body>
</html>

<?php
    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that *mysql_* functions are deprecated, I don't think that's where the problem lies. If you want the selected data being shown below the drop down list, you'll need to update the page using AJAX or reload the page.

Comment: I changed the link to an image. This is helpful to those who are looking at your post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit your form on change of select like this,

```
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

In your case its,

```
echo "<select name='sub1' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";
```

`mysql_*` are deprecated, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead

---

These lines are completely wrong

```
$result2=mysql_query($sql);// what is $sql here??
$base=mysql_fetch_array($result2);

$nnnn = $_GET[$row];// what is $row??
$aaaa = $_GET["base"]; // where is the form element with name base??
$bbbb = $_GET["hauteur"]; // where is the form element with name hauteur??
$cccc = $_GET["rayon"]; // where is the form element with name rayon??
```

Comment: The bottom part of their code/your answer; it's pretty obvious it should be `$base` and not `$_GET`. As for `$_GET[$row];` yeah that one's unclear.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yes ur correct. I just added what was there in question. Thats why i have asked questions to OP.

Comment: Thank you ;) What I want to do is as you see in this link: http://www.faouweb.net/test/page3.php        here a capture of the DB  http://oi62.tinypic.com/2uzbdib.jpg thank you :)